# Flex multiple collapsible elements per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have multiple collapsible elements in a flex div but when I expand only one element from row it pushes all content down from that row. I have an example
in JSFiddle, can anyone help? Thanks

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zsc1pnxj/1/

```
<div class="element-collapsable">
                <div class="header-element" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                    Header 1
                </div>
                <div class="body-element collapse show" id="collapseExample1">1</div>
            </div>

            <div class="element-collapsable">
                <div class="header-element collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                    Header 2
                </div>
                <div class="body-element collapse" id="collapseExample2">2</div>
            </div>

            <div class="element-collapsable">
                <div class="header-element collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                    Header 3
                </div>
                <div class="body-element collapse" id="collapseExample3">3</div>
            </div>

            <div class="element-collapsable">
                <div class="header-element collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                    Header 4
                </div>
                <div class="body-element collapse" id="collapseExample4">4</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: The rows have a content-based height. So when the content expands, the row expands. Not sure what you ultimately want. Maybe set a fixed height to the row?

Comment: I would want that header 4 to stay under header 2 without moving when I expand/collapse header 1.